# iPhone web-app (built on jQTouch) - animations jerky since iOS 5

Tags: iphone, html, web-applications, ios5, jqtouch

In July I built an iPhone web-app using jQTouch. On iOS 4 I had no problems with the web-app: The built-in jQTouch animations (slide left, slide right) etc were smooth as silk.

However, since the upgrade to iOS 5, these core page transition animations (slide left, slide right and flip) have become very jerky.

The web app can be found [here](http://sdt-app.dconnell.co.uk) (please add it to your home screen on your iOS 5 iPhone):

To see the effect, once it's added to your home screen, start the app and keep tapping the main buttons - Speed, Distance or Time.

I've done a lot of Googling and have found nothing, though I'm sure that other developers must have been / will be affected by this issue.

The issue is not just limited to my 3GS device as I have tried it on other people's devices (including iPhone 4) and I see the same issue, but only on iOS 5.

Stuff I have tried:

- updating my jquery.js to different versions - including the latest - animations still jerky
- updating jQTouch to the latest version - animations still jerky
- stripping out all JavaScript, only leaving jQTouch and its initialization - animations still jerky
- removing all of my custom css, only leaving the default jQTouch CSS - animations still jerky
- removing all CSS, apart from just the CSS3 animations in jqtouch.css - animations still jerky
- removing html elements - i noticed that when i removed all of the *select* and *input* elements from the web app, the animations became smooth again. However, there is nothing strange about the mark-up or CSS attached to these elements. Could this issue simply be to do with having too many elements on the page at once during an animation?

So it seems this issue is to do with HTML elements rather than JS or CSS, although I really can't figure out why...the mark-up is all valid **apart from** the iphone specific attributes i've used such as *placeholder* and *autocapitalize* etc.

Strange thing is that the animations on the [jQTouch demo](http://jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/) still seem smooth on iOS 5.

Any help/suggestions much appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit**: Also, the button on the 'Info' page that 'bounces' has become jerky too. This uses the jQuery UI bounce effect. This was animation completely smooth on iOS 4.

Comment: Runs as well as any other webapp on my iPhone 3G[s].

Comment: Yessir, just tried it out again and it's still running smoothly for me.